# Passing the same context variable to multiple function views

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is there any efficient way to pass the same context to multiple views? This is what I mean:

```
def first(request)
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})

def home(request)
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'form': form})

def profile(request)
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

As you can see I'm passing the same context to multiple views. It's a context I have to pass to basically every view as it's a uniform variable I need throughout the website. Is there any way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Are you basically wanting the same form in everypage? Like a login form? or feedback form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with views so I don't know if the type will let you do this, but could you, instead of returning the `render()` results, store that in a list and use it?

What I mean is like this:

```
def all(request): 
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    my_list = ["base", "homepage", "profile"] `
    end_list = [] 
    for item in my_list: 
        end_list.append(render(request, item + '.html', {'form': form})
    return end_list
```

If render is returning a variable type, then this should work. You can access each of the views rendered from the list, and you can just add more types to `my_list` if you have more views to render. If it's not returning something that can be collected like this, then I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can describe base view.

```
def base(request, template_name):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

first = lambda request: base(request, template_name='base.html')
home = lambda request: base(request, template_name='homepage.html')
profile = lambda request: base(request, template_name='profile.html')
```

**However** if you are looking for a better solution i would suggest you [Django CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/). This looks much cleaner and support DRY.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from .forms import SomeForm

class BaseView(View):
    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class FirstView(BaseView):
    template_name = 'base.html'

class HomeView(BaseView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class ProfileView(BaseView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
```